# What is "7k run"?

Tags: word-meaning, abbreviations, jargon

What is "7k run"? I didn't find any sense in a respective dictionary entry that would match the context

[image: Summary of January 2023 headlines from BBC website]

This is the text,

> My work day: 4am start, **7k run** and cold showers

Comment: It's when you run for 7 kilometres. I feel sure that '7k' ought to be understood across other languages, so this isn't really a question about English.

Comment: This meaning of "k" is listed in dictionaries.

Answer (score 5):

7k is runners jargon for "seven kilometers"

In most contexts kilometre would be abbreviated "km" - The use of just "k" isn't widespread, except by runners.  Even then there are subtleties to the jargon. Eg 5000m is a track run, but 5k is a road or cross-country run. 7k is acceptable but 7m would be odd for 7 miles, even though this is widely used on road signage.

More generally "k" is used to mean 1000, and understood in context

> I'm earning 50k now!

> When you reach 15k you can mark questions as "protected".

Comment: But on Stack Exchange 7K would be short for "7 thousand reputation”...

Comment: Obviously 7K run (in reputation) would not make sense but it could be the reason for the OP's confusion.

Comment: The letter "k" is also widely used in finance to mean a thousand units of currency, as in: 
      "An income of €/$/£100k a year".